# Python regex separate space-delimited words into a list

Tags: python, regex, string, list

If I have a string = "hello world sample text"

I want to be able to convert it to a list = ["hello", "world", "sample", "text"]

How can I do that with regular expressions? (other methods not using re are acceptable)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
"hello world sample text".split()
```

will split on any whitespace. If you only want to split on spaces

```
"hello world sample text".split(" ")
```

regex version would be something like this

```
re.split(" +", "hello world sample text")
```

which works if you have multiple spaces between the words

Comment: Both of your solutions work if you have multiple spaces between words

Comment: @Mike, the behaviour of `str.split` is slightly different when the split string is specified as a space, multiple spaces will be split because they have empty string between them.